# Update Knockout Observable Array from another view model

Tags: javascript, mvvm, knockout.js

It seems to be a complicated scenario. But I would try to break down it simple.

In a viewmodel , I have an Observable Array that is bound to a dropdown.

```
(function () {
    UserMgmt.PeopleViewModel = WebFramework.BaseViewModel.inherits({

    initializeViewModel: function (options) {
        this.initializeBinding(options);
    },
    initializeBinding: function (options) {
        .......
        .......
        this.intGroups = ko.observableArray([]);
        .......
        getGroupsForSite: function (cb) {
            this.setListValue('/GetGroupsForSite', { siteId: '123', startIndex: 0, maxRecordCount: 20 }, this.intGroups, cb);
        },
        setListValue: function (api, data, observable, cb) {
            this.postDataRequest(api, data, function (err, result) { //Gets teh data from service
                if (!err && result) {
                    observable(result.data);
                    if (cb) { cb(); }
                }
            });
        },
    ....
)},
```

Now from this page a popup opens that has a different viewmodel and u can save a new group info there.

But while closing the modal popup, that previpus page's `dropdown value needs to updated
with this saved value`.

**Can I do it via observableArray ?**

So that , I can update from this new viewmodel and without reloading the whole previous page, it updates only the dropdown ?

Here is the second view model ....

```
   UserMgmt.IntrusionGroupListViewModel = WebFramework.BaseViewModel.inherits({
    initializeViewModel: function (options) {
        this.initializeBinding(options);
    },
    initializeBinding: function (options) {
        this.ErrorMessage = ko.observable("");
        this.IsError = ko.observable(false);


        SaveNewGroup: function () {

            debugger;
            //this.setListValue('/GetGroupsForSite', { siteId: '123', startIndex: 0, maxRecordCount: 20 }, this.intGroups, cb);
        }
}
```

How can I achieve the desired functionality ?

What should be inside **SaveNewGroup()** for it to work ?

Answer (score 0):

The code that instantiates the two viewmodels should pass either the first viewmodel or its `intGroups` member as one of the `options` to the second viewmodel. The second viewmodel then has access to what it needs. You can modify the observable array and changes will show up in the view.

If, for some reason, there is no code that knows about both viewmodels, you will need to use [Postbox](https://github.com/rniemeyer/knockout-postbox) to communicate between the two.